# After Genymotion update - This error started Unable to wait on alarm: Device or resource busy

Tags: java, android, genymotion

I'm a newbie to Java and Android.  I updated Genymotion and my virtual devices and since then my files get hung up with this error in the logcat.  I'm using Android Studio.

538-572/? E/AlarmManagerService﹕ Unable to wait on alarm: Device or resource busy

I've run several different Android Studio projects but I get the same error so I'm thinking it's not a coding problem since the projects ran fine before.

I get the error when I run the projects on the genymotion emulator and my hardware/phone.

I've researched this error but I haven't found any explanations or fixes.

It may not have anything at all to do with Genymotion but I was not getting this error prior to the update.

Comment: If you get the same error on your physical device, then your Genymotion update have nothing to do with your error. 

The error you show means you probably did something wrong with Alarms. you should try to isolate the problem, and provide code source for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  The problem is resolved although I'm not sure how.  I could never figure out what was actually causing it.  I reinstalled virtual box, rebuilt my project and updated android studio and no longer got the error.